# Owned type issue when migrating from Entity framework core 2.0 to 2.1

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1, entity-framework-core-2.1, entity-framework-core-migrations

We are upgrading our asp.net core app (which runs on the full .net framework) from asp.net 2.0 /  ef core 2.0 to asp.net 2.1 / ef core 2.1.
I'm surprised how much of a headache it is for a minor update...

Anyway, after upgrading to 2.1 and adding a migration without any code changes to the model, EF creates a migration to move a owned type that we use (the only one) to a separate table.
Why?
The [documentation][1] states otherwise:

> When using relational databases, by convention owned types are mapped
>   to the same table as the owner.

We can fix the issue by adding a ToTable() and passing the name of the parent entity, but we don't understand why this is required in the first place.

Before:

```
builder.Entity<Chart>().OwnsOne(c => c.BarLineOptions);
```

After:

```
builder.Entity<Chart>().OwnsOne(c => c.BarLineOptions).ToTable("Chart");
```

We also attempted to remove this fluent configuration with the new OwnedAttribute but it causes the same problem so we really need the fluent config to call `ToTable()`

Update: If we don't create the migration, we get an exception when starting the app saying the table BarLineOptions doesn't exist

Comment: Can you provide the Chart model class

Comment: It doesn't happen by default (you can easily verify that with clean project). There must be some unusual configuration like "custom naming convention" by iterating `modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()` and setting table name (I've seen people doing that). If yes, make sure it skips `entityType.IsOwned()`.

Comment: Thank you Ivan, that was indeed the issue. We fixed it by adding a if (!entityType.IsOwned()) in our fluent config. Feel free to post an answer and I will accept it.